# How to select text without the HTML markup

Tags: python, html, xpath, web-scraping, lxml

I am working on a web scraper (using Python), so I have a chunk of HTML from which I am trying to extract text. One of the snippets looks something like this:

```
<p class="something">This class has some <strong>text</strong> and a few <a href="http://www.example.com">links</a> in it.</p>
```

I want to extract the text from this class. Now, I could use something along the lines of

```
//p[@class='something')]//text()
```

but this leads to each chunk of text ending up as a separate result element, like this:

```
(This class has some ,text, and a few ,links, in it.)
```

The desired output would contain all the text in one element, like this:

```
This class has some text and a few links in it.
```

Is there an easy or elegant way to achieve this?

**Edit**: Here's the code that produces the result given above.

```
from lxml import html

html_snippet = '<p class="something">This class has some <strong>text</strong> and a few <a href="http://www.example.com">links</a> in it.</p>'

xpath_query = "//p[@class='something']//text()"

tree = html.fromstring(html_snippet)
query_results = tree.xpath(xpath_query)
for item in query_results:
    print "'{0}'".format(item)
```

Comment: What HTML parsing library are you using?

Comment: I'm using lxml, I've updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could call `.text_content()` on the lxml Element, instead of fetching the text with XPath.

```
from lxml import html

html_snippet = '<p class="something">This class has some <strong>text</strong> and a few <a href="http://www.example.com">links</a> in it.</p>'

xpath_query = "//p[@class='something']"

tree = html.fromstring(html_snippet)
query_results = tree.xpath(xpath_query)
for item in query_results:
    print "'{0}'".format(item.text_content())
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `normalize-space()` in the XPath.  Then

```
from lxml import html

html_snippet = '<p class="something">This class has some <strong>text</strong> and a few <a href="http://www.example.com">links</a> in it.</p>'
xpath_query = "normalize-space(//p[@class='something'])"

tree = html.fromstring(html_snippet)
print tree.xpath(xpath_query)
```

will yield

```
This class has some text and a few links in it.
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternate one-liner on your original code: use a `join` with an empty string separator:

```
print("".join(query_results))
```